# create m lines using a 2D numpy array and a 1D array using matplotlib or seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a one-dimensional numerical array `A`, with size `n`; and have a matrix `B` with size `m*n`. Each row of `B` and `A` can be used to create a line. In other words, the B and A can be used to create m lines in a plot. How to achieve this using `matplotlib` and `seaborn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through matrix `B`, and plot line with `A` where `A` as x points and rows in `B` as y points.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = 3
n = 15

A = np.random.rand(n)
B = np.random.rand(m, n)

fig = plt.figure()
axes1 = fig.add_subplot()

for i, B_ in enumerate(B):
    axes1.plot(A, B_, label=i)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]